# Create shiny app which will be presenting data published by eurostat

Tags: r, shiny, visualization

I wrote a code but something is wrong.

This is exact exercise--->
Data can be found at https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/population-demography/demography-population-stockbalance/
database?node_code=demomwk

The application should enable:

1. downloading the latest data from the EUROSTAT website;
2. will enable the selection of a set of countries whose data will be presented;
3. will allow you to choose the years of data that will be presented;
4. will enable the selection of genders for which data will be presented;
5. will present selected data in tabular form in the following format:
6. COUNTRY; SEX; WEEK; NUMBER;
7. visualize data aggregates on the map of EUROPE;
8. total for the indicated period, for the indicated sexes, in the country;
9. visualize selected data in the form of time series;
10. one time series for selected genders, for each country separately;

```
install.packages(c("shiny", "eurostat", "dplyr", "ggplot2", "leaflet"))

library(shiny)
library(eurostat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)

# define UI dla Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Mortality Data from EUROSTAT"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("countries", "Select countries:",
                  choices = c("All", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus",
                              "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France",
                              "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy",
                              "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands",
                              "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia",
                              "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom")
      ),
      selectInput("years", "Select years:",
                  choices = c("All", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005",
                              "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012",
                              "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020")
      ),
      selectInput("genders", "Select genders:",
                  choices = c("All", "Males", "Females")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput("map")),
                  tabPanel("Time Series", plotOutput("time_series"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# define server logic for Shiny app
server <- function(input, output) {
  # download latest data from EUROSTAT website
  data <- get_eurostat(id = "demomwk", cache = TRUE)
  
  # data flter
  data <- data %>%
    filter(if (input$countries == "All") TRUE else geo == input$countries) %>%
    filter(if (input$years == "All") TRUE else time == input$years) %>%
    filter(if (input$genders == "All") TRUE else sex == input$genders)
  
  # table
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data %>%
      select(geo, sex, week, value) %>%
      rename(COUNTRY = geo, NUMBER = value)
  })
  
  # map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = data, lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude)
  )
  }
```

i tried a lot of things and i dont know what i should do with that to work

Comment: Where/When did you first encounter an issue in the app making process?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. First, `demomwk` is a name of a topic in the Eurostat database but not the name of a table. Maybe you meant `demo_r_mwk_ts` which is a table of deaths by country, sex, year and week. Second, as you want to filter for `country` and `sex` labels you have to call `get_eurostat` with argument `type="label"`. Third, to filter the data based on the user input you have wrap the `filter` inside a `reactive` which I called `data_filtered`. Fourth, the way you tried to implement a conditional filter will also not work, so I fixed that too. Fifth, ....

To get you started, here is working app:

Note: I uncommented your leaflet map. The Eurostat data does not contain any geo data. To this end you have to add some data with the longitude and latitude where you want to add the country markers or in case of a choropleth map get a shape file of european countries. Also, as the data contains deaths per year and week you also have to take account of that, too.

```r
library(shiny)
library(eurostat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)

# define UI dla Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Mortality Data from EUROSTAT"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("countries", "Select countries:",
        choices = c(
          "All", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus",
          "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France",
          "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy",
          "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands",
          "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia",
          "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom"
        )
      ),
      selectInput("years", "Select years:",
        choices = c(
          "All", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005",
          "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012",
          "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"
        )
      ),
      selectInput("genders", "Select genders:",
        choices = c("All", "Males", "Females")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table")),
        tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput("map")),
        tabPanel("Time Series", plotOutput("time_series"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# define server logic for Shiny app
server <- function(input, output) {
  # download latest data from EUROSTAT website
  data <- get_eurostat(id = "demo_r_mwk_ts", cache = TRUE, type = "label", time = "raw")
  
  # data flter
  data_filtered <- reactive({
    data %>%
      tidyr::extract(time, into = c("year", "week"), "(\\d{4})W(\\d{2})") %>% 
      { if (input$countries == "All") . else filter(., geo %in% input$countries)  } %>%
      { if (input$years == "All") . else filter(., year %in% input$years) } %>%
      { if (input$genders == "All") . else filter(., sex %in% input$genders) }
  })
  
  # table
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_filtered() %>%
      select(geo, sex, year, week, values) %>%
      rename(COUNTRY = geo, NUMBER = values)
  })
  # 
  # # map
  # output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  #   leaflet() %>%
  #     addTiles() %>%
  #     addMarkers(data = data, lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude)
  # })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5258
```

[image]